# Azure instance - my direct changes were lost

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, azure

I have a small production instance on Azure for my web app.  To quickly make changes to the live site, I open the instance via RDC and copy across any dlls and files that need to be added.  That seemed to be working fine.

However, last night, the instance seemed to have been reset (I'm still investigating why) and the version of the site was rolled back to a month or so ago.

I have read on StackOverFlow that any changes made via RDC are not saved when an instance reset is performed by Microsoft and that it rolls back to the previous Publish.

Surely there has to be a quicker way to make changes to a production instance than having to Publish the app each time?  Each Publish takes approximately 45 minutes.  If I'm making multiple deployments per day then is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, all changes must be published.
Microsoft garantees that there will be an working instance but no garantees that it will be same instance.

We were looking for other solutions but now just publish changes.
But we are probably lucky to waste 10 minutes to publish.

Comment: Thanks Denis.  I'll look into blob storage to reduce the publishing time.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can look at:

1. The size of your ***.cspkg** file. Try to shrink the *.cspkg file to reduce the upload time. You could store static files like images, videos, ... in blob storage for example.
2. Use a synchronization mechanism that synchronizes all files from a blob container to your IIS website. If you use this you can simply copy the files to blob storage in order to update your instance. Note that there are things you need to consider, like what happens to your startup tasks, what about rolling upgrades, ... ? Steve wrote a great blogpost about this: [Update Your Windows Azure Website in Just Seconds by Syncing with Blob Storage](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/update-your-windows-azure-website-in-just-seconds-by-syncing-with-blob-storage) (this uses a WorkerRole instead of a WebRole)
3. Go for Windows Azure Web Sites, this allows you to deploy **immediately** using FTP, [Git](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-git/), ...

Comment: Thanks for the useful links.  I don't use blob storage so that's something I'll have to change in order to reduce the deployment times.